# Can I trick Carbonite into backing up an external hard drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, carbonite

I use [Carbonite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonite_%28online_backup%29) to back up my PC (Windows XP). We were running low on disk space on our home PC (down to 15 GB), so I went out and purchased an external hard drive.  However, Carbonite will not back it up. Is it possible to set up Carbonite to backup an external hard drive?

I just want the external drive to be extra disk space. From their FAQ:

> The current version of Carbonite backs
>   up only the files that reside on
>   permanent hard drives on your
>   computer.
>
> It will not back up network drives,
>   external drives, and NAS (network
>   accessed storage) drives. If there are
>   files on a remote drive that you wish
>   to include in your Carbonite backup,
>   you should copy the files to a folder
>   on your local hard drive. If the files
>   are on a shared network drive, you
>   could install Carbonite on the
>   computer on which the network shared
>   drive physically exists, and back the
>   files up directly from that computer.
>
> Check back soon for a Carbonite
>   service plan that will allow you to
>   back up your external drives.

Comment: Not very ethical I would google on your own.  Just get a 1TB drive and toss it in your computer and have it back that up.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: I am running Windows XP - just updated the question.

Comment: I'd say it can be ethical ! I have the same situation. In this case an old laptop (permanently stationary) and no way to add an internal drive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is an ethical dilemma or a Carbonite capabilities issue. That being said...

Have a look at this MS Knowledge Base article: [How to create and use NTFS mounted drives in Windows XP and in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307889). You can "mount" the external drive as a folder off of your internal drive.

Comment: Mounting the external drive as a folder did the trick.

Comment: This didn`t work for me on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

[CrashPlan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrashPlan) supports USB drives.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to your Carbonite problem, but while researching online backup systems recently, I found [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com). They will [backup external disks](http://www.backblaze.com/remote-backup-everything.html) (though not network-based storage).

Besides switching services, upgrading your internal drive (or adding another one, if you have an extra bay) seems like the best way forward. “Disks are cheap”, right?